# unable to import .mdb into hadoop

Tags: hadoop, import, sqoop

I would like to import a locally stored .mdb (MS Access) file into hadoop, but sadly all my attempts failed so far. I tried it with sqoop but i dont know how to modify the import path for my local machine.
Any Idea how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Bes wishes
Jonas

Comment: Do you really want to process MS access data with Hadoop?! How big is your document?

Comment: Better option is just to use the programming language that you are comfortable with and harvest your MS Access data. Hadoop or Sqoop for that purpose are just ...

Comment: Yes the idea is to automatically collect tons of .mdb files, stored on various computers in my network and write the content into hadoop.